# TensorFlow Permission Denied Error /Location

Tags: python, linux, tensorflow

Following [this tutorial](https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_demo) when I run board.py in my terminal I get this error on Ubuntu 16.04:

```
 File "/home/alarik/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/errors_impl.py", line 469, in raise_exception_on_not_ok_status
    pywrap_tensorflow.TF_GetCode(status))
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.PermissionDeniedError: /LOCATION
```

I'm a relatively new Linux user/programmer so I'm not entirely sure what to do here/look up as google hasn't found me the answer. So my two questions are:

1. How should I go about resolving this
2. In the future how should I go about troubleshooting errors similar to this as to become more independent

Comment: It seems like a linux file system issue, id suggest verifying that , in linux you can obtain files permissions using ls -l <path>, can you post the output of that here?

Comment: ls -l <path> bash: "syntax error near unexpected token `newline'"

Comment: Ohhh, sorry i didnt wrote it clear, <path> is a placeholder , you have to replace <path> by the path you want to analyze. Right now i think its a permissions issue with your tensorflow installation,so id suggest replace <path> by the location of your tensorflow installation directory.

Comment: and another test, i suppose you are running board.py executing :python board.py , can you try : sudo python board.py ?

Comment: I believe you may be correct, I ran sudo python board.py and now it says there's no module tensorflow.. which is odd as when type import tensorflow as tf in the shell it works, same goes for my other programs that import tf.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `/LOCATION/ON/YOUR/COMPUTER/` in [line 56](https://github.com/llSourcell/tensorflow_demo/blob/master/board.py#L56) to the correct location where the user has write permissions, for example, `./summaries` (`summaries` folder in the current working directory).

`/` is owned by root and typical users have no write permissions there.